# Can we write a gRPC gateway in .NET Core using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, microservices, grpc

I have close to 10 micro services written in .NET Core 3.1. They are basically a .NET Core web API project with http endpoints exposed as REST.

My requirement is I have to make these micro-services communicate to each other via http2 / gRPC mode of communication instead of http rest.

After some googling found that by using [https://medium.com/swlh/rest-over-grpc-with-grpc-gateway-for-go-9584bfcbb835](https://grpc%20gateway) we can expose a rest endpoint for a gRPC service and vice versa.

My question is how to write a gRPC gateway in C# in .NET Core, do we have any in built Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 templates for this?

All I want to do is for 2 micro-services to communicate to each other via gRPC protocol.

Any comment would be helpful as I am very new to this concept.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore

Comment: thank you for the response, Now I am clear as to how to use grpc services in .Net core, my questuon is - can we write a gRPC gateway in .Net core ? gRPC gateway is the one which can expose a grpc service as a rest http endpoint.

Comment: https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion